# how do I add virtual network to api management with terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

how do I add virtual network to api management?
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/api_management.html#virtual_network_configuration
A virtual_network_configuration block supports the following:
subnet_id - (Required) The id of the subnet that will be used for the API Management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the subnet Id as it shows in Terraform. Here is an example code:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


data "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
    name             = "default"
    virtual_network_name = "vnet-name"
    resource_group_name = "group-name"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "example-apim"
  location            = "East US"
  resource_group_name = "group-name"
  publisher_name      = "My Company"
  publisher_email     = "company@terraform.io"

  sku_name = "Developer_1"

  virtual_network_type = "Internal"

  virtual_network_configuration {
      subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.example.id
  }

  policy {
    xml_content = <<XML
    <policies>
      <inbound />
      <backend />
      <outbound />
      <on-error />
    </policies>
XML

  }
}
```

And you can change the virtual network type as you need, also for other properties. I use the existing Vnet, you can create a new one or also use the existing one, it all depends on yourself.